# Which software does Chrome uses to display PDFs from html while printing?

Tags: google-chrome, pdf-generation

Which software does Chrome uses to display PDFs from html while printing? Are there any wrappers available to use it from .net framework etc.?

Answer (score 1):

I am not very familiar with the chromium [codebase](http://code.google.com/searchframe#OAMlx_jo-ck/src/third_party/skia/src/pdf/), but it appears that they are using [skia](http://code.google.com/p/skia/) a C++ library. I couldn't find any C# wrappers for it.